# how to change the placeholder in prompt

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I have the code below based on langchain, and I want the retrieval to update the `context`, but the prompt is not updated.

*Note: I need the system prompt to be selected by some logic, this is why I defined it with the placeholder. ( the logic is not part of the example )*

```
template = """Answer the question based only on the following context:
{context}

Question:
"""

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="system"),
        ("user", "{question}")
    ]
)



chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(system=lambda x: [SystemMessage(content=template)])
    | RunnablePassthrough.assign(context=lambda x: retriever.invoke(x["question"]))
    | prompt
)

chain.invoke({"question": "What I need to do to run FOSS scan?"})
```

the result is:

```
ChatPromptValue(messages=[SystemMessage(content='Answer the question based only on the following context:\n{context}\n\nQuestion:\n'), HumanMessage(content='What I need to do in order to run FOSS scan?')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consulted with one of my colleagues, here is the recommendation

```py
chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(content=lambda x:
                                 retriever.invoke(x["question"]))
    | RunnablePassthrough.assign(system=lambda x:
#                              [SystemMessage(content=template)])
                               [SystemMessage(content=PromptTemplate.from_template(template).format(context=x["content"][0].page_content))])
    | prompt
)
```

1. Retrieve the data
2. Set `system` template dynamically, instead of using static `content`